# Broke up Express app into submodules - now my custom "x-powered-by" does not work

Tags: node.js, express

I watched the tutorial [here](http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/38571504626/modular-web-applications-with-node-js-and-express):

.. and got inspired to break up my ever-growing application into distinct modules.  The high level structure is as follows (some parts deleted for brevity):

server.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , orgs = require('./lib/orgs');

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
  app.disable('x-powered-by');
  app.use(orgs);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

lib/orgs/index.js

```
var express = require("express")
  , app = module.exports = express()
```

It works great.  However, I have a small problem which may lead to bigger problems going forward.  When I structure my app this way (e.g. having express 'submodules'), the x-powered-by is not disabled, which leads me to believe that all app config stuff is not read as well.  I have tried to place the disable message before and after calling the orgs submodule.

Can someone please help me understand this?  Thanks

Comment: It really seems that the settings are not carried down, because the apps are separate express apps. You could either reuse your configure block or use a different application style like [bumm](https://github.com/saintedlama/bumm) suggests, where you separate your application with different route files. Is not that separated but suffices for medium size apps.

Comment: that's a really good question! I've got the same problem

Comment: See https://github.com/visionmedia/express/commit/fa8eec449bf406cebd7a92d376a098a39a804879

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was identified as a bug and has since been fixed here:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/commit/fa8eec449bf406cebd7a92d376a098a39a804879